# XSLT for xml to EDI

Tags: xml, xslt, edi

Is there any sample xslt available which I can use as reference to migrate xml to edi format. 
More precisely, I am looking for 837 format files.

Regards,

Shishir Kumar Mishra

Comment: If you provide a small XML fle and the exact wanted result and explain what are the rules that the XSLT transformation should comply with, then someone could provide the wanted transformation. We don't know what edi is neither what 837 is.

Comment: It would be nice to have sample instance(s).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a source XML document and need to convert it to EDI, ***USE A TRANSLATOR***.

If you're looking for open source (free), Java based transformation solution - check out Jitterbit.  It has an intuitive mapper and would allow you to transform XML into EDI.

If you have a budget, check out Delta and ECS from Liaison.  For less than $20K you'll have software that will do the transformation, provide you with a full EDI dictionary, and give you a set of tools to extend past this current project.

Transforming an XML document into an 837 using XSLT and code, well you're just asking for trouble, headaches and heartaches.  There are so many widely available commercial tools to do what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your response.  I had created xml schema to represent HIPAA docuements. Then I generated .NET object from it was populating values into that. XSLT would have provided us  facility to write more dynamic code but in lack of time we had to use SDK from http://edidev.com/ .

Comment: I have to disagree with: << you're just asking for trouble, headaches and heartaches >> ;-) For me, << $20K >> gives worse heartaches than << XSLT >> ;-)

Comment: That's fine to disagree with me.  I know you have been in the EDI world for awhile and have commercial solutions to sell, so I respect your opinion :)  Would you prefer I recommended a $50K+ solution from Sterling Commerce or the like?  The fact of the matter is you're doing two transformations, when you get get a tool that only does one (talking straight XML to EDI).  XSLT + code would get the job done, but it's a one off solution.  If you bought software meant to do this, it would open up A2A, B2B possibilities and not just solve ONE problem/project..  Worth the $$$, IMHO

Comment: Not to mention the 837 can be a real b*tch.  Most people in the US complain about the 856.  To steal a quote from BTO, "you ain't seen nothin' yet".  Rolling your own..it's a big challenge.  Especially if you don't fully understand EDI, which is another topic altogether.

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed, with a $20K software solution, you have already made a (big) step away from the << $50K + solution from Tuuuut >> ;-)
Regarding my "commercial" solution, it's not yet "commercial", a few people are using for free at the moment, and it might never be ;-) I still have a debate with myself about opening the source code of what I have done... "SerialiseEDIFACT.xsl" is a small 1st step.

Comment: @Andrew: I would to make one IMPORTANT correction to your statement: << XSLT + code would get the job done, but it's a one off solution. >> I am not working on one-off solution, but I am working on a complete/exhaustive "framework" that handles A2A, EAI, B2B, EDI, etc ;-)

Comment: @Shishir Kumar Mishra: It would be nice to sample instance(s) so I can demonstrate some stuff ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you're looking for X12 or EDIFACT.  The [X12](http://xml.x12.org/index.php) site does offer XML Schemas but you have to register.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I am using X12. Looks like this site does not offer anything for 837 (professional or institutional).

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what I am doing, using XSLT to handle EDI.

You should do your transformation into 2 XSLT steps:

```
(1) Your XML -------------------- XSLT#1 --> XML representation of 837

(2) XML representation of 837 --- XSLT#2 --> 837
```

The XSLT#2 would be a "universal" script which can serialized any XML-ized X12.

I have done such a "universal" script for EDIFACT, see http://code.google.com/p/parse-edifact/source/browse/trunk/Serialiser/SerialiseEDIFACT.xsl.

If you create by-hand one resulting 837 you want to get, I can do the step (2) for you, and if you know a bit of XSLT you will see how easily you can do the step (1).

Comment: Thanks Babel for the offer.I had created schema for Xml representation of 837 so I dont need step 1 anyways because .NET does that for me. 
I was looking for Step 2 but as of now we have decided to use  EDIDEV sdk for second step.

Comment: You're welcome ;-) According to my personal EDI experience, I would still recommend step #1. I usually recommend the "export" program - your .NET development - to use its own grammar, close to the internal data model of your application, instead of directly issuing the grammar needed by the recipient! It will allow you to re-use your interface, a new recipient would then mean a new XSLT#1, but no change on the export program! But, that would require a switch from .NET development to XSLT scripting ;-)

Comment: Anyway, following this post, someone else did contact me, with EXACTLY the same request, so I will have my change to create the "SerialiseX12.xsl" ;-)
I will then probably combined my EDIFACT and X12 work within my open-source project BabelEDI ;-) I will keep you updated via this thread ;-)
Good luck with EDIDEV ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the open source [X12Parser](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/). The source code has some good X12 XSLT schemas in it (though they're built specifically for use in the parser).  Or just modify the parser to suite your needs.  It does a good job of transforming X12 to and from XML.